# Qt - the object receiving the signal

Tags: qt, object

In a `Qt` application, if we have the following for example:

```
.
.
.
QApplication a(argc, argv);
.
.
.
QObject::connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
.
.
.
```

Here, I know `button` is the object that will send the signal. Thus, `a` is the object that will respond to the signal. In this case, `a` is a `QApplication` object. But, what does it really represent? For example, we knew that `button` is a button object, then what does `a` represent? Is it simply a *window*?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [read the docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qapplication.html#details), QApplication's role is well documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QApplication` does not represent any visual element. Instead it represents the whole "program" - which is of course something of more abstract a nature.

Answer (score 0):

Citing from the [Qt documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qapplication.html)

```
The QApplication class manages the GUI application's control flow and main settings.
```

The most important task of a `QApplication` instance is handling events: Whenever you move the mouse, for example, the application receives events from the OS (or window system), which the `QApplication` instance will dispatch and forward to your GUI. Also, when you `emit` a signal, `QApplication`'s event loop will call the connected slots.

Other tasks in which `QApplication` is involved:

- Command line parsing
- Styling (choosing the right look for the widgets depending on the OS)
- Session management
- Translations/Internationalization